# on click update css transform: scale() property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, scale

I have an org chart I created where the top-level-node has a scale of 1.5 (all other children/sibling nodes are set to a scale of 1).  I have an Expand All Nodes button that when I click it, before the org chart appears, I would like to return the top-level-node scale to 1 (so it is the same size as the now-expanded nodes) but for the life of me I cannot get it to change back.

I've tried applying varying levels of specificity, using the !important declaration and all sorts of jQuery hackery but to no avail.  Below is the code in question:

**CSS**

```
/*Top Level Node*/
.orgchart .node:first-child {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

/*All Other Nodes*/
tr.nodes td table tr td div.node {
 transform: scale(1) !important;
}
```

**jQuery** (Wrapped in $(document).ready(function() {});

```
'use strict';

(function($){

  $(function() {

    var datascource = {...};

    var orgChartInstantiation = function() {

        var options = {...};

        // ********************
        // Expand all nodes
        // in company org chart
        // ********************

        $("button#expandNodesButton.btn.btn-default").on("click", function() {

            //
            // Code below is what I'm having an issue with
            //
            $("div.node.first-level.topLevelNode").css("transform", "scale(1)");

            var options = {...};

            $("#my-org-chart").empty(); //clear previous contents 
            $("button#expandNodesButton.btn.btn-default").toggle(); //toggle display for corresponding collapse button
            $("button#collapseNodesButton.btn.btn-default").css("display", "block");

            $("#my-org-chart").orgchart(options);

        });

    };

    orgChartInstantiation();

  });

})(jQuery);
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you mean it's not settings "scale(1)"? Are you sure the selector is correct because it doesn't match the CSS selector. Can you provide a full example (include a jsfiddle)?

Comment: Sure let me work on that and I'll post it momentarily.  I've tried using the selector I optioned for in the CSS in my jQuery but that wouldn't work either @musefan

Comment: Ahh I fixed it...haha unreal

Answer (score 0):

OK so I was able to figure out a working solution (albeit maybe not very elegant but working, nonetheless).

Rather than trying to change the scale back to 1 by way of doing:

```
$(".orgchart .node:first-child").css("tranform", "scale(1)");
```

I was able to do:

```
$(".orgchart .node:first-child").css("transform", "none");
```

I'm not sure I understand WHY I wasn't able to just reset the scale to 1 and instead had to use "transform", "none" but will do some homework and report back if I find anything of note!